# how to add execution permission (+x) to all scripts

Tags: linux, permissions, find, chmod

we have under /var/scripts/.../.../..

a lot of script as ( .sh .bash .py )

```
/var/scripts/.../.../klo.py
/var/scripts/.../.../klo.sh
/var/scripts/.../.../kjrbom.py
.
.
.
.
```

how to add for these scripts the execution permission +x , by find command

find need to add to all scripts that ended with ( .sh / .bash / .py )  the +x  permissions

```
find /var  ......... chmod +x .....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `find`:

```
find /var/scripts/ -type f -regex '.*\.\(py\|sh\|bash\)$' -exec chmod +x {} +
```

You might want to check the files first:

```
find /var/scripts/ -type f -regex '.*\.\(py\|sh\|bash\)$'
```

- `-regex '.*\.\(py\|sh\|bash\)$'` matches file(s) ending in the given three patterns
- `-regex` matches the whole filename, hence we need `.*` to match anything at start